# Calculus $3$: Vertex, equation for tangent plane, normal line at $P_0$?

Tags: calculus

If $P_0(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is a point on the cone $z^2=a(x^2+y^2)$.What is the equation of the tangent plane and normal line at $P_0$?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Please read http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960 and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you edit your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Use implicit function differentiation
$$
z^2 = a \left( x^2+y^2 \right ) \\
\left \{ \begin{array}{ccc}
2z z_x &=& 2ax \\
2zz_y &=& 2a y
\end{array} \right . \implies \left \{ \begin{array}{ccc}
z_x &=& \frac {ax}z \\
z_y &=& \frac{a y}z
\end{array} \right .
$$
So, tangent plane is
$$
z-z_0 = \frac a{z_0} \left[ x_0(x-x_0) + y_0(y-y_0) \right ]
$$
You can leave it this way – it's a legitimate answer, but you can simplify further too, if you will.
\begin{align}
z-z_0 &= \frac a{z_0} \left[ x_0(x-x_0) + y_0(y-y_0) \right ] = \frac a{z_0} \left [x_0 x + y_0 y - \color{red}{x_0^2 - y_0^2} \right ] = \\
& = \frac a{z_0} \left [x_0 x + y_0 y - \color{red}{\frac {z_0^2}a} \right ] = a \frac {x_0 x + y_0 y}{z_0} - z_0
\end{align}
or after some manipulations
$$
z_0 z = a \left( x_0 x + y_0 y\right )
$$
is an equation of the tangent plane.

As for the equation of the normal line, it has directional vector $a$ which is normal vector $n = (ax_0, ay_0, -z_0)$ of the tangent plane, so
$$
\frac {x-x_0}{ax_0} = \frac {y-y_0}{ay_0} = -\frac {z-z_0}{z_0}
$$